# Shuffle object of objects or display randomly elements in Angular 2 in template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I have an object of objects with structure like this:

[image]

And I display all images in my template with help of Object.keys

in component I have:

```
this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

in template:

```html
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
  <li *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(newTmp)">
    <img src="{{newTmp[key].url}}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

For now everything works fine, but **I would like to shuffle my images**, so each time the page will be refreshed, the images will change their order.

I know, that Objects don't have defined order, so it's not possible to manipulate data in the component. I don't want to make an array of it, because an idea of object is quick search through objects (i will have in future thousands of thousands of images and looping trough an array is not good solution in this case, so I'd like to keep object instead of an array)

My question is: what could be possible solution here? Is there any possibility to reorder the images direct in template without touching component? Or maybe there is some way to shuffle objects?

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array

Comment: Please post your structure as plain text, as some people don't have access to imgur because of proxy reasons.

Comment: You may want to use a library like lodash to more easily deal with collections. [`shuffle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#shuffle) is a commonly implemented function in these, among others.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a pipe, and include it in the `declarations` array of the `AppModule`.

`src/app/core/pipes/random-order.pipe.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'randomOrder' })
export class RandomOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    const newList = [...list];
    newList.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    return newList;
  }
}
```

`src/app/app.module.ts`

```
import { RandomOrderPipe } from './core/pipes/random-order.pipe';

@Module({
  declarations: [RandomOrderPipe, ...],
  ...
})
```

`src/app/app.component.html`

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="item in list | randomOrder">
    <!-- -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very clean and complete solution. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

To create a shuffling function, you need to work with arrays. What you can do is as you did, getting the keys, but it would be easier and more intuitive to directly use an array.

After all, it represents a list of pictures, so it should not be an object.

The shuffle function can be coded with the help of `reduce` and `splice` :

```js
const images = ['dog', 'cat', 'degu', 'mouse', 'snake'];

function shuffle(list) {
  return list.reduce((p, n) => {
    const size = p.length;
    const index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (size - 1));
    p.splice(index, 0, n);
    return p;
  }, []);
};

console.log(shuffle(images));
console.log(shuffle(images));
console.log(shuffle(images));
```

Comment: (This is Javascript code, but it is valid Typescript, so you can simply copy and paste it into your component)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array returned by object.keys by using a random boolean generator in the sort callback:

```
this.objectKey = (obj) => {  
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => Math.random() >= 0.5);
};
```

Below, you can see the random sort in action:

```js
var objectKey = (obj) => {  
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => Math.random() >= 0.5);
};

var obj = { prop1: '1', prop2: '1', prop2: '1', prop3: '1', prop4: '1', prop5: '1' };

console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const images = [{'name':'user01'}, {'name':'user02'}, {'name':'user03'}, {'name':'user04'}, {'name':'user05'}];

function shuffle(list) {
  return list.reduce((p, n) => {
    const size = p.length;
    const index = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (size - 1));
    p.splice(index, 0, n);
    return p;
  }, []);
};

console.log(shuffle(images));
console.log(shuffle(images));
console.log(shuffle(images));
```

```js
var objectKey = (obj) => {  
    return Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => Math.random() >= 0.5);
};

var obj = { prop1: '1', prop2: '1', prop2: '1', prop3: '1', prop4: '1', prop5: '1' };

console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
console.log(objectKey(obj));
```

Comment: Answer could do with some explanation, use the edit button bottom left to add details